# PostgreSQL - convert lexemes to full words via ts_stat

Tags: postgresql, text, tsvector

I trying to get counts of words to generate a word cloud type view from my PostgreSQL db. I was hoping to take advantage of the built in efficiencies of ts_vectors. I see that there is a ts_stats function that returns a list of lexemes and their frequencies, given a ts_vector column.

The rows returned look something like this:

```
word    ndoc    nentry
studi   322     43434
compani 233     2322
```

And the query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ts_stat('SELECT tsv from doc')
ORDER BY nentry DESC, ndoc DESC, word
LIMIT 10
```

However, I need the full word, not just the lexemes. Is there a way to convert a lexeme to one of its full-word representations with PostgreSQL? You can easily convert a word to its lexeme, but I can't figure out how to do the reverse.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No, I settled for a far less efficient solution of pulling lots of text into my application code and doing the counts after some rudimentary stemming. Thinking I'll take a look at DBs more geared toward full-text search...

Answer (score 3):

Change the configuration of your ts_vector to 'simple'.  the default is 'english' which does the stemming
e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM ts_stat('SELECT to_tsvector(''freds company company company hello ridiculous'')');
```

outputs counts for `ridicul, compani, hello, fred`

with the 'simple' configuration no stemming occurs

```
SELECT * FROM ts_stat('SELECT to_tsvector(''simple'',''freds company company company hello ridiculous'')');
```

outputs counts for : `ridiculous,hello,freds,company`

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible. You can store the initial text into a separate column.

A lexeme is a normalized representation (using dictionary or stemmer) of a word, so it can match several forms: lexeme `'walk'` matches `'walks'` and also `'walking'`, so the original form cannot be determined.